# al hacer fetch a un json local no encuentra el archivo .json javaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente codigo que hace un fetch a la url local que trae info de un json, pero cuando clone el repositorio en otra carpeta y ejecutoe l proyecto no encuentra el json, lo mismo cuando hago el deployment, si es una ruta local como podría hacer para que encuentre el archivo json

siempre obtengo Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) data.json

Debo hacerlo con la ruta absoluta? si es el caso como se podría hacer?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
const searchingValue = async (searchingValue) => {
    const getItems = await fetch('../data.json');
    const json = await getItems.json();
    const infoArray = json.data;
    console.log(typeof infoArray);
    //filtering by btn value
    infoArray.map((single_data)=>{
        if(single_data.category === searchingValue){
            renderingInfo(single_data);
        }else if(searchingValue === "All"){
            renderingInfo(single_data);
        }
    });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La ruta del `data.json` debe ser relativa a la que ves en la barra de dirección del navegador. Si estás en `index.html` y ambos archivos están en el mismo nivel, entonces no es necesario retroceder; elimina `../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getItems = await fetch('../data.json');
```

¿Por qué los dos puntos antes? Eso significa la carpeta arriba del archivo. Quieres solo uno, o ningúno.  Como explica [Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) en su comentario:

```
const getItems = await fetch('./data.json');
```

O también:

```
const getItems = await fetch('data.json');
```